# IIS 10 returning 200 for 404 page

Tags: web-config, iis-8.5, iis-10

I have the following server configuration on my staging and production server for a custom 404 page, and I am performing some operations based on 404 URLs on my custom 404 page. And getting status as 404 for a non-existing page is necessary for the operation I am performing on my custom 404 page.

```
<httpErrors>
    <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

With the above configuration on the production server, I am getting 200 status code for a 404 page but the same is working fine on my stagging server. The only difference between my stagging and production server is that staging is on IIS 8.5 and production is on IIS 10. I m not able to get what missing to achieve the same on the IIS10 production server.

Comment: There is no change in IIS 8.5 and IIS 10.  ExecuteURL always return 200 status code for your custom error page.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/. If your want to return 404 status with custom page, then you should use insert content with static file instead of php error page. Could you post more screenshot for the symptom and IIS configuration?

Comment: Let's say I am  checking the header of this path "/mypage.php" which doesn't exist and on stagging I am getting 404 and on production, I am getting 200 with same the same config, please let me know which part of config you want to see screenshot off

Comment: I tested the same operation on event older IIS7 and executeURL return 200 as well.It is reommended to enable failed request tracing and compare the logs. It should tell us why IIS return different status in different machine.